# D3 Display Text from API Call

Tags: d3.js

I'm having problems displaying a piece of text from an API call using d3.json.

I have an html file
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lnag="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="d3.v5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="canvas"></div>
</body>

<script src="index-API.js"></script>
</html>
```

I have the js file
**index-API.js**

```
//THIS WORKS
const canvas = d3.select(".canvas").append("svg")
.attr("width", 500)
.attr("height", 500)
.style("background-color", "lightgreen");

canvas.append("text")
.text("this works")
.attr("fill", "red")
.attr("font-size", 20)
.attr("x", 100)
.attr("y", 150)

//THIS DOESN'T WORK
d3.json("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
.then(data =>{
    console.log(data);

    const canvas2 = d3.select(".canvas").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 500)
        .attr("height", 500)
        .style("background-color", "lightblue");

    canvas2.selectAll("text")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("fill", "red")
        .attr("font-size", 20)
        .attr("x", 100)
        .attr("y", 150)
        .text(function (d) { return d.title; })

        console.log(canvas2);
    });
```

The api call to https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 returns this object

```
{completed: false
​id: 1
​title: "delectus aut autem"
​userId: 1}
```

What am I not doing correctly above to get the title: "delectus aut autem" to show up as text in the lightblue section?

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Put the data into square brackets: `.data( [data] )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide `selectAll().data()` either an array or a function. You're providing an object. If you have only one object you wish to display, you can take one of two approaches:

One, place your data in an array:

```
 canvas2.selectAll("text")
     .data([data])
```

```js
d3.json("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
  .then(data =>{

    const canvas2 = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 500)
        .attr("height", 500)
        .style("background-color", "lightblue");

    canvas2.selectAll("text")
        .data([data])
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("fill", "red")
        .attr("font-size", 20)
        .attr("x", 100)
        .attr("y", 150)
        .text(function (d) { return d.title; })

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Your other option, again, if you only have one element you want to plot, is to use:

```
canvas2.append("text")
   .datum(data) // allows you to access the datum later in your chain.
```

```js
d3.json("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
  .then(data =>{

    const canvas2 = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 500)
        .attr("height", 500)
        .style("background-color", "lightblue");

    canvas2.append("text")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("fill", "red")
        .attr("font-size", 20)
        .attr("x", 100)
        .attr("y", 150)
        .text(function (d) { return d.title; })

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew! super helpful to see the differences in the code snippets and to learn about the existence of the datum method.